# Packet tracer 7.2.2 close on login

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, cisco, error-logging

when i try to login on packet tracer after putting my mail the program closes and this shows on my terminal.

```
:~$ sudo packettracer  
Starting Packet Tracer 7.2.2
/usr/local/bin/packettracer: línea 8:  3352 Excepción de coma flotante   (`core' generado) ./PacketTracer7 "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1
:~$
```

the error in spanish says something like : line 8: 3352 Floating point exception ( 'core' generated)

I had to install a packet tracer on a newly installed ubuntu 18.04.3 I followed [this](https://linuxhint.com/install_packet_tracer_ubuntu_1804/) guide, with the exception that instead of .tar.gz I had to download the PacketTracer-7.2.2-ubuntu-setup.run, it has to be the version 7.2.2. I had it installed and working until recently that I had to format my computer.
Also if I close the login window I can see that the UI it's loaded but since I didn't log in it closes.

additional information:

```
:~$cat /var/log/syslog
[...]
Jan 27 19:32:00 skynet kernel: [ 5160.136825] traps: PacketTracer7[4124] trap divide error ip:7f2540ec7ef4 sp:7fff1119dc80 error:0 in libQt5XcbQpa.so.5[7f2540e0b000+111000]
```

Answer (score 0):

as for now I could bypass my problem by installing a virtual machine with a windows 10 and running packet tracer there, I hope this is just a temporary solution.